# R - Mutate new variable with string information from other variables

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr

For my MSc thesis I'm sorting out a data file in R. In this file there are string values which are not in the right columns. I'm trying to order them, or mutate new columns where the new column only takes a string if it matches a certain regular expression. Let me show you what I mean. For illustrative purposes I've made the following dataframe. Here, 4 people were asked to give their first and second favourite colour and food, or only first if they had only one favourite (NA is also possible). However, due to some error, the answers are mixed over 4 columns.

```
     df <- data.frame(person_ = c("Peter", "Lucas", "Jake", "Harry"), 
             note1 =c("1. Red", "2. Green", "1. Food: Hamburger", "1. Food: Pizza"), 
             note2 =c("1. Food: Pasta", "1. Blue", NA, "1. Yellow"),
             note3 =c("2. Food: Spaghetti", "2. Food: Chips", "1. Red", NA),
             note4 =c("2. Purple", "1. Food: Pancake", "2. White", NA))
```

What I would like to know is how I can order these. You can recognise the first and second favourite by the '1. ' and '2. '. And you can recognise the favourite food by 'Food: '. This fact immediately makes me think I have to work with regular expressions. I have thought about it and tried mutating new columns and having the values be picked out from the columns 'note1', 'note2', 'note3' or 'note4' and matching a regex. I didn't manage....

For all clarity, this is what I ultimately want.

```
    df_1 <- data.frame(person_ = c("Peter", "Lucas", "Jake", "Harry"), 
               note1 =c("1. Red", "2. Green", "1. Food: Hamburger", "1. Food: Pizza"), 
               note2 =c("1. Food: Pasta", "1. Blue", NA, "1. Yellow"),
               note3 =c("2. Food: Spaghetti", "2. Food: Chips", "1. Red", NA),
               note4 =c("2. Purple", "1. Food: Pancake", "2. White", NA),
               fav1_color =c("Red", "Blue", "Red", "Yellow"),
               fav2_color =c("Purple", "Green", "White", NA),
               fav1_food =c("Pasta", "Pancake", "Hamburger", "Pizza"),
               fav2_food =c("Spaghetti", "Chips", NA, NA))
```

Do any of you have an idea how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` from the new `tidyr`:

```
dfnew<-df %>% pivot_longer(-person_, names_to="note",values_to="value") %>%
  mutate(note=gsub("(\\d)\\. (\\w*\\:)?.*","\\1 \\2",value), value=gsub("(\\d\\.) (\\w*\\:)? ?(.*)","\\3",value)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = note, values_from = value, names_prefix = "fav")

dfnew
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  person_ `fav1 ` `fav1 Food:` `fav2 Food:` `fav2 `
  <fct>   <chr>   <chr>        <chr>        <chr>  
1 Peter   Red     Pasta        Spaghetti    Purple 
2 Lucas   Blue    Pancake      Chips        Green  
3 Jake    Red     Hamburger    NA           White  
4 Harry   Yellow  Pizza        NA           NA
```

There's still room for improvement in the column names, but this should take you most of the way to your goal.

--

Just for completeness' sake, here's a full solution including an automation of the column names:

```
dfnew<-df %>% pivot_longer(-person_, names_to="note",values_to="value") %>%
  mutate(note=gsub("(\\d)\\. (\\w*\\:)?.*","\\1\\2",value), value=gsub("(\\d\\.) (\\w*\\:)? ?(.*)","\\3",value))
dfnew$note<-ifelse(!grepl(":",dfnew$note),paste0(dfnew$note,"colour"),dfnew$note)
dfnew2<-dfnew %>% mutate(note=tolower(gsub("(\\d)(\\w*)?:","\\1\\2",note))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = note, values_from = value, names_prefix = "fav") %>%
  select(order(sapply(sapply(strsplit(names(.),""),rev),function(x) paste0(x,collapse=""))))


# A tibble: 4 x 5
  person_ fav1food  fav2food  fav1colour fav2colour
  <fct>   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     
1 Peter   Pasta     Spaghetti Red        Purple    
2 Lucas   Pancake   Chips     Blue       Green     
3 Jake    Hamburger NA        Red        White     
4 Harry   Pizza     NA        Yellow     NA
```

Comment: Thank you for this. With the simple addition of rename() it works perfectly :

%>% rename("fav1_colour"="fav1 ","fav2_colour"="fav2 ","fav1_food"="fav1 Food:","fav2_food"="fav2 Food:")

Comment: I see. This will do for me. Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: Just for the fun of it, added a full solution including automating the column naming

Comment: Thank you. Now it's perfect.